# how to load the local files relative to the current java file in jwebbrowser

Tags: java, jwebbrowser

how would I load local files relative to the current java file in JWebbrowser? 
I know that I could load my page with `navigate("path");` the problem is how to set relative path!

for example my java code is in :
   D:\Eclipse_Project\MyProject\src\javaCode\browser.java
and the html file is in :
   D:\Eclipse_Project\MyProject\src\pages\html.html

but I don't want to use as follow:

```
webBrowser.navigate("file:///D:/Eclipse_Project/MyProject/src/pages/html.html");
```

Edit:

my html file also contains CSS an javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still actual, I had the same problem, this is the solution:

you need to use webserver like that:

```
webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
webBrowser.navigate(WebServer.getDefaultWebServer().getClassPathResourceURL(getClass().getName(), "your_html_content.html"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following code:
1. Read html content with scanner.
2. Set html string to webBrowser.

```
String webContent = new Scanner(new File("src\\pages\\html.html")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
webBrowser.setHTMLContent(webContent);
```

Comment: I try it, but it didn't run load the page correctly!

Comment: Does your html.html is pure html file without any javascript and css local dependent files?
I've tried that it should work, make sure your relative path is correct. By default "user.dir" should be your project working directory.

Comment: It contains javascript and css!

Comment: In that case, I guess you need to make sure your html.html should import the right path of js and css files with a relative path.

Comment: Please paste your html.html out.

Comment: I think I find the problem, in my javascript code I need to load some picture which is located in src/images/pic.png. so how should I address it in my html.html file so that it could find it?!

Comment: try to use "../images/pic.png" or just <%=request.getContextPath()%>/... Anyway, that's a problem of relative path, just print some log and reset path will easy to work, I think.

Comment: sorry that I ask to much question! `"../images/pic.png"` and  `<%=request.getContextPath()%>../images/pic.png` didn't work!